# ionic 3 display data from woocommerce rest api

Tags: json, ionic-framework, ionic3

im having a hard time displaying the data i got from woocommerce on my ionic 3 app, i have accessed the data successfully and displayed it on console.log the way i wanted, but im not being able to do so in html.

the data i want to display are the coupons list based on user email address, here is the function i used to display the data in consol log:

```
  coupon: any;

  couponz() {
    var data=[];
    for (let co of this.shared.couponz){
    data.push({ code: co.code, coEmail: co.email_restrictions[0], expiry: co.date_expires });
    if (co.email_restrictions[0] == this.shared.customerData.email) {
       this.coupon = co.code
      console.log(co.code)
      }
    }
  }
```

and here is how i got the data in my shared provider:

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedDataProvider {

  public couponz;

this.config.Woocommerce.getAsync("coupons/").then((data) => {
  this.couponz = JSON.parse(data.body);
});
```

so any idea how to get it displayed in html?

thanks

Comment: You should be able to interpolate `this.coupon` directly in the HTML using `{{coupon}}` - have you tried this?

Comment: thank you for your response, i did try that already, it only displays 1 item